# pylibftdi Device.read skips some bytes

Tags: python, fpga, ftdi

I have an FPGA that streams data on the USB bus through an FT2232H and I have observed that about 10% of the data has to be thrown away because some bytes in the frame are missing. Here are the technical details:

- FPGA is an Artix 7. A batch of 4002 byte is ready every 9 ms. So that works out to 444,667 byte/s of data.
- My laptop runs python 3.7 (from anaconda) on Ubuntu 18.04LTS
- The FPGA/FT2232H is opened via the following initialization lines:

```
SYNCFF = 0x40
SIO_RTS_CTS_HS = (0x1 << 8)
self.device = pylibftdi.Device(mode='t', interface_select=pylibftdi.INTERFACE_A, encoding='latin1')
self.device.ftdi_fn.ftdi_set_bitmode(0xff, SYNCFF)
self.device.ftdi_fn.ftdi_read_data_set_chunksize(0x10000)
self.device.ftdi_fn.ftdi_write_data_set_chunksize(0x10000)
self.device.ftdi_fn.ftdi_setflowctrl(SIO_RTS_CTS_HS)
self.device.flush()
```

- Then the data is read via this simple line:

`raw_usb_data = my_fpga.device.read(0x10000)`

I have observed the following:

1. I always get `0x10000` of data per batch, which is what I expect.
2. Reading 2**16 = 65,536 byte at once using device.read should take 147.4 ms given that a batch is ready every 9 ms. But timing that line gives a mean of 143 ms with a std deviation of 6.6 ms.

My first guess is that there is no buffer/a tiny buffer somewhere and that some information is lost because the OS (priority issue?) or python (garbage collection?) does something else at some point for too long.

**How can I reduce the amount of bytes lost while reading the device?**

Comment: Is the FPGA sending binary data, but you are telling the `Device` to be in text mode?

Comment: Yes, good point. The FPGA sends binary data, read by Device in text mode and then cast to `bytes` for processing. I need to update that, but I can confirm that I faced the same issue when Device was set to binary mode. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: The FT2232H features 4kB internal buffers. Chances are that you are limited by them. For my application I use pyserial and a subprocess which collects the data and send them via a pipe to the main process to workaround the GIL. Pipes themselve have an internal buffer of ~8kb under windows so sometimes one has to tweak it as well. Not sure what plibftdi is doing internally and if switching to plain VCP would be an option for you.

Comment: Ah and the "deviation" is normal as we are talking about USB. It behaves basically like a "shared packet oriented pipeline" with sloppy timing warranty. One can reduce the latency by changing the drivers latency setting (at least under windows) but never get ride of it.

Comment: Ah! I did not know all of that. Thanks for the information. Do you have links to example codes I could use to get started with people? I have never used that package but if I can get around the GIL and finally be able to stop dropping bytes, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FT2232H has internal FIFO buffers with a capacity of ~4 kbits. Chances are that you are limited by them. Not sure how pylibftdi deals with them but maybe using an alternative approach might work if you can use the VCP driver. This allows you to address the FT2232H as standard comport e.g. via pyserial.

Some excerpts from one of my projects which actually works for baud rates >12 Mbps (UART is limited to 12 Mbps but e.g. fast opto can reach ~25 Mbps):

```
import traceback
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.connection

def IO_proc(cntr_pipe, data_pipe):
    try:
        search_str="USB VID:PID=0403:6010 SER="
        ports     = [x.device for x in serial.tools.list_ports.comports() if search_str in x.hwid]
        baud_rate = 12000000 #only matters for uart and not for fast opto or fifo mode
        ser       = serial.Serial(port, baud_rate)

    while not cntr_pipe.closed:
        time.sleep(0)
        in_data = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())

        [...do some pattern matching, package identification etc...]

        data_pipe.send_bytes(in_data)

        except EOFError:
            ret_code = 2
        except Exception as e:
            cntr_pipe.send(traceback.format_exc())
            cntr_pipe.close()
            ret_code = 4
        finally:
            cntr_pipe.close()
            ser.close()

multiprocessing.connection.BUFSIZE = 2 ** 20 #only required for windows
child_cntr, parent_cntr = multiprocessing.Pipe()
child_data, parent_data = multiprocessing.Pipe()
process                 = multiprocessing.Process(target = IO_proc, args=(child_cntr, child_data))

#called frequently
def update():
    if child_cntr.poll():
        raise Exception("error",child_cntr.recv())

        buf = bytes()

        while parent_data.poll():
            buf += parent_data.recv_bytes()

    [...do something fancy...]
```

I tried to c&p a minimum example. It is untested so please forgive me if it is not working out of the box. To get this working one actually needs to make sure that the VCP and not the D2XX driver is loaded.

P.S: Actually while scanning through my files I realized that the pylibftdi way should work as well as I use a "decorator" class in case the D2XX driver is loaded:

```
try:    import pylibftdi
except: pylibftdi = None


class pylibftdi_device:
    def __init__(self,speed):
        self.dev = pylibftdi.Device(interface_select=2)
        self.dev.baudrate = speed
        self.buf = b''

    def write(self, data):
        self.dev.write(data)

    def read(self, bytecount):
        while bytecount > len(self.buf):
            self._read()

        ret      = self.buf[:bytecount]
        self.buf = self.buf[bytecount:]
        return ret

    def flushInput(self):
        self.dev.flush_input()#FT_PURGE_RX
        self.buf = b''

    def _read(self):
        self.buf += self.dev.read(2048)

    @property
    def in_waiting(self):
        self._read()
        return len(self.buf)

    def close(self):
        self.dev.close()


def find_device_UART(baudrate=12000000,index=1, search_string="USB VID:PID=0403:6010 SER="):
    if pylibftdi:
        return pylibftdi_device(baudrate),"pylibftdi_device"
    try:
        ports = [x.device for x in serial.tools.list_ports.comports() if search_string in x.hwid]
        module_logger.info(str(ports))
        if len(ports) == 0:
            return None,"no device found"
        else:
            ser = serial.Serial(ports[index],baudrate)
            return ser,"found device %s %d"%(ser.name,ser.baudrate)
    except serial.SerialException as e:
        return None,"error during device detection - \n"+str(e)
```

So main difference to your example is that the recv buffer is read more frequently and put into a buffer which is then searched for the packets later on. And maybe this all is a complete overkill for your application and you just need to make smaller read calls to ensure the buffers never overflow.

Comment: That sounds like a plan, thanks a lot for the example code! Do you foresee a difference in performance between the two methods?

Comment: In my experience the main limitation arises from the relative small internal buffers of FT2232H and the lack of buffering higher amounts by the driver. So frequent and regular reads are of essence. So as you have pylibftdi already up and running I would mostlikely stick with it.

Comment: Ok I'll try that next week and see how much I can reduce the amount of frames dropped.

Comment: I have tried several options with mixed results. 

First, I moved the reading portion of the code to a separate process that communicate through a Pipe. The only thing that this process does is reading the FPGA.

Second, I tried to read the FPGA very frequently for short duration and put that in a buffer for later processing -> it did not help, very short reads might actually have made the situation worse.

So my next option is to give pyserial a chance, but I doubt pylibftdi is garbage: I must have overlooked something here.

Comment: Not everything is bad though: the code looks much cleaner now

Comment: @Shinagan it is strange that your code suffer data lose then. BTW it just realized that no baud rate is set; In what mode does the FT2232H operate? FIFO, UART, FAST OPTO, ... ?

Comment: Rate is not set and when I read the baudrate with `Device.baudrate` it says 9600, but I definitely read the data much faster than that. I do not know what mode I am using, but the Device class has a `flush` method that per the documentation _Instruct the FTDI device to flush its FIFO buffers_. So I assume I am in FIFO mode by default? Last, I made sure that everything was read in binary from the device (see the very first comment by @quamrana) to be consistent throughout the code and I have consistently seen < 5% frames dropped lately. But not 0. The read subprocesses uses < 10% CPU.

Comment: @Shinagan This is were the naming gets confusing: The FT2232H supports multiple modes. One of them is called FIFO but one can describe it as "8 bit parallel connection". On the other hand the FT2232H has internal buffers which work in First In First Out fashion. The flush method does a "clear/dump"  of those (internal) buffers. If the flush method is called all the stored data is lost. Knowing the mode of operation might help to identify the root of the faced problem.

Comment: From the pylibftdi doc I found that `The default mode of pylibftdi devices is to behave as a serial UART device`. So I would be in UART mode? Is there a way to check from python or else the device mode? I searched for FIFO and UART in the doc and did not find much more. I'm sorry I am only providing limited info, this is beyond what I know on FTDI devices so I learn at the same time as I troubleshoot! Last: regarding baudrate, I found that `In parallel mode, the actual bytes-per-second rate of parallel data is 16x the programmed BRG value.` So the actual baudrate might be 153,600 - still short

Comment: @Shinagan Easiest way is to check how your FPGA is actually sending the data. The mode of the FT2232H is determined by the presence/absence of an EEPROM, the within stored settings and the driver access. The FT2232H datasheet has a table which tells which mode is accessable under which condition. AFAIK the baudrate only matters for UART and the speed of e.g. FIFO and FASTOPTO is actually defined by the applied clk and not the driver settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198731/discussion-between-shinagan-and-christian-b).